# Redis-cluster Helm chart unable to complete job when using istio

Tags: redis, istio, redis-cluster

When using the Bitnami Helm chart for Redis-Cluster, there is a redis-cluster-cluster-create job. However, when enabling istio-injection, this job never ends. If I disable istio-injection, the job quickly ends. Any solutions or reason why this phenomenon is happening?

Comment: Hi @IHateMint, the main issue here is that  job is not considered complete until all containers have stopped running, and Istio sidecar run indefinitely, while your task may have completed, the Job as a whole will not appear as completed in Kubernetes. There is [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324) about that. Could you try to use this [workaround](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324#issuecomment-587980168) and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: Hi @Jakub, I can change the podAnnotations from Redis-Cluster Helm Chart, and when disabling the istio-injection, the Job doesn't spin up istio-proxy. However, the main job 'cluster-create' job never ends, and eventually fails the the deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the main question

> there is a redis-cluster-cluster-create job. However, when enabling istio-injection, this job never ends. If I disable istio-injection, the job quickly ends. Any solutions or reason why this phenomenon is happening?

The main issue here is that job is not considered complete until all containers have stopped running, and Istio sidecar run indefinitely, while your task may have completed, the Job as a whole will not appear as completed in Kubernetes.

There is [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324) about that.

There is one of the [workarounds](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324#issuecomment-587980168), and you can find more workarounds [here](https://medium.com/redbox-techblog/handling-istio-sidecars-in-kubernetes-jobs-c392661c4af7).

---

> I can change the podAnnotations from Redis-Cluster Helm Chart, and when disabling the istio-injection, the Job doesn't spin up istio-proxy. However, the main job 'cluster-create' job never ends, and eventually fails the the deploy

As mentioned [here](https://medium.com/redbox-techblog/handling-istio-sidecars-in-kubernetes-jobs-c392661c4af7)

> So as a temporary workaround adding sidecar.istio.io/inject: “false” is possible but this disables Istio for any traffic to/from the annotated Pod. As mentioned, we leveraged Kubernetes Jobs for Integration Testing, which meant some tests may need to access the service mesh. Disabling Istio essentially means breaking routing — a show stopper.

So it might actually not work here. I suggest to try with the quitquitquit as it's the most recommended workaround.

---

Additionally worth to check these github issues:

- [List of applications incompatible with Istio](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14743)
- [helm stable/redis does not work with istio sidecar](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/5453)
- [Using Istio with CronJobs](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11659)
- [Sidecar Containers](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/753)